# How to maximize a ContentPage in net maui for a Mac Catalist

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I need to maximize a ContentPage, but I can't find any method to do it. In a windows application it would be windows.Maximize().

Is there any equivalent in net Maui for Mac Catalist ??

Thank you

Comment: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/windows#mac-catalyst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no direct equivalent of the `windows.Maximize()` method in Mac Catalyst .

However, you can set page size in .NET MAUI for macOS using the following code snippet:

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
}

private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
#if MACCATALYST
    this.Window.MinimumHeight = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height;
    this.Window.MinimumWidth = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width;
#endif
}
```